# How to remove rows from CSV file based on value and existence of that value in another CSV file

Tags: csv, duplicates

Basically the dataset I downloaded included duplicate People, which I removed using `sort`, but those duplicate rows were also referenced in another csv file, I'd like to remove those rows. Here's the overview; three CSV files:

**person.csv**:

```
personID,personName
1,tom
[...]
```

**job.csv**:

```
jobID,jobName
job_1,programmer
[...]
```

**person_job.csv**

```
personID,jobID
1,job_1
[...]
```

Some of the personIDs in the `person_job.csv` do not exist in `person.csv`. So what I need to do is remove the rows in `person_job.csv` where the `personID` does not exist in `person.csv`.

How can I do this? I'm on OS X, and I'm open to using any method (ruby/perl/awk/python/whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using Ruby, here's how:

- Create an array (called a) of IDs in person.csv
- Create an array    (called b) of IDs in person_job.csv
- Create a third array of the    difference between a & b (`c = b - a`). This array contains IDs of    the rows we need to delete from `person_job.csv`

Create a table from person_job.csv:

`table = CSV.table('person_job.csv')`

Delete from the table if the ID appears in array c:

```
table.delete_if do |row|
    c.include? row[:person_id]
end
```

write the table to a CSV, which I will use to replace `person_job.csv`:

```
File.open('person_job.csv', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(table.to_csv)
end
```